# Can't download SQL Server from Sql official site

Tags: sql-server

From https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/sql-server/sql-server-downloads link when I click on the download I get an error as shown in the screenshots:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Works fine for me; perhaps your ISP/firewall/VPN/Workplace is blocking it.

Comment: Worsk fine for me. Check things suggested by @Larnu